# tkinter need to click in shell to get gui fields to update

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter gui with Python 3.4.2 in which there are various buttons, a user entry field and a text field. Everything works except that I appear to have to click in the Python shell (IDLE) and out of the gui to get fields to update in response to button presses. The updates are immediate when I click on the shell. I have copied this tkintergui from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1156637 which gives the same problem on my Mac. Immediate update if IDLE shell clicked or very slow update in the GUI

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

class SimpleEdApp:
    def __init__(self, parent=Tk()):
        self.mainWindow = (parent)
        self.mainWindow.title("Simple Editor")
        self.mainWindow.resizable(0, 0)
        self.make_mnu()
        self.make_txt()

    def make_txt(self):
        self.text = Text(self.mainWindow, width = 80, height = 40, background = 'white')
        self.scrollY = Scrollbar(self.mainWindow, orient = VERTICAL, command = self.text.yview, troughcolor = 'white')
        self.text["yscrollcommand"]  =  self.scrollY.set
        self.scrollY.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        self.text.pack(expand = TRUE, fill = BOTH)

    def make_mnu(self):
        self.menubar = Menu(self.mainWindow)
        self.filemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff = 0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = self.file_open)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = "Save as...", command = self.file_save)
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = self.mainWindow.destroy)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.filemenu)      
        self.mainWindow.config(menu = self.menubar)

    def file_open(self):
        filename =askopenfilename(filetypes=[("pythonfiles","*.py"),("tclfiles","*.tcl"),("allfiles","*")])
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        self.text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.text.insert(1.0, data)

    def file_save(self):
        filename =asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("pythonfiles","*.py"),("tclfiles","*.tcl"),("allfiles","*")])
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        data = self.text.get(1.0, END)
        f.write(data)
        f.close()


app = SimpleEdApp()

app.mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Grateful for correct implementation

Comment: It will help if you state the platform and how you run this application (eg: Linux, ./script using #!/usr/bin/python or windows and a doubleclick using ActiveState python etc.). You are failing to process the event loop - probably waiting for input somewhere. Clicking IDLE is most likely flushing the event queue for you.

Comment: Just tried it on my Mac, running it from CLI and it works fine. Have you tried running it outside of IDLE?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. How do I run it outside of IDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. This looks to be a bug in IDLE.

In the comments you asked how to run the program outside of IDLE. To do that, open up a prompt and type the command `python myfile.py`, where `myfile.py` is the name of your python file (assuming "python" is in your PATH).

*note: depending on what is installed in your system, you may need to use `python3` rather than `python`.

Comment: @Xenomorph: on the other hand, his shebang is "/usr/bin/python", so "python" may be an alias to "python3".

Comment: Works in termina. Thank you for your help everyone. Thank you for the initial suggestion to use the terminal. I have learned a lot from this and boned up on its use.